# CSS display:table and display:table-cell alternative for fixed widths

Tags: css

I thought I'd discovered something pretty great with the display:table and display:table-cell properties for making navigations more responsive and fluid-like, with the display:table applied to the ul with table-layout: fixed; and the li's given the display:table-cell all added lines fit within the ul perfectly, irregardless of borders or any other added elements (unlike percentage based widths), with no floating required and working as far back as IE8 which makes for minimal cross browser compatibility styling.

Unfortunately, however.. Firefox decided that a position could not be applied to an element displayed as a table-cell, which means that the element in question can not be a parent to another element with say... absolute positioning. Which ends up meaning Firefox will center and float your secondary level navigation vertically attached to the body tag, or something else in the background with a correct position. (Kind of comical that this works as far back as IE8, but not Firefox).

Anyhow, I digress.

Has anyone found a suitable alternate method that does NOT use percentage based widths to combat this?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle with minimal code , so you can get relevant advise :) (to hide show: left:-9999px/left:auto witout relative :)

Comment: okay, another hint: use display:flex with display:table as fallback for older ie

Comment: As you requested, here is the minimal Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h95bv/ as you can see, the dropdown works on Chrome, IE but not FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FF absolute positionning you may not need to reset specific `left` coordonate, nor `top` coordonates when you want to see in screen area your element.

See **[this example](http://jsfiddle.net/h95bv/1/)** where `top` and `left` are left to `auto` .

I added a `box-shadow` , so you see where each element `ul` or `li` , stands.

You can then decide to deal with `padding` and `margin` instead coordonates.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so very much, not just for solving my problem, but for explaining it too. Sincerely, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. just remenber sometimes , too much styling rules can become an handicapp or bring up unwanted interactions :)